# Как включить спящий режим экрана

Tags: java, android

Я кнопкой хочу включать и выключать спящий режим в приложении. Включать я знаю как:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

а вот как выключать не спящий режим у меня не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Можете почитать про флаги в документации:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags(int)